# Call to a member function insert() on a non-object (During Installation Process)

Tags: magento-1.9, database, install

I'm trying to install Magento 1.9 on my localhost, but when I add database details and click on "Continue button" during installation, I am getting below error.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Resource.php on line 133
```

**line 133 on  Resource.php**

```
public function getConnections()
    {
        return $this->_connections;
    }
```

Why this error occurs and any solution to resolve this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento cannot instantiate the database connection. Usually this means, your `app/etc/local.xml` is missing or does not contain the right database credentials.

Since it happens during installation, your entered database details are probably not correct.